# internal encoding for my application

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

My desktop c# application gets various documents from users, possibly in different encodings.

I need to show users existing documents, allow to manipulate them in my UI, and store them for future use.

Adding the notion of "encoding" to each of these steps seems complex to me. I was thinking to internally always convert the user input documents to UTF-8, and so my UI and data store do not need to worry about it. Then when the user wants the document back as a file I ask the user which encoding to use.

Does this make sense? Are encodings interoperable? What if I only support unicode?

Comment: utf8everywhere.org. There's nothing more to say about encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encodings are not interoperable, since some have characters that others don't have.

Unicode internal representation is a good idea since it has the wider charset, but I'd advice to save back the document in the original encoding if the added characters are still in the said encoding. If not, prompt the user that you'll save in Unicode in order to encode correctly these characters.

Comment: so utf-8 and utf-16 are interoperable? assuming I only care for unicode, I can immediatelly convert every input document to utf-8, and all my internal UI controls and DB will use it. Then when the user wants to export back I can ask again which encoding to use (or in future save the user a bit of work by having an "original encoding" field). Does this make sense?

Comment: yet utf8 and utf16 are interoperable. If you convert documents to unicode it means you know their encoding, so yes you can save that in an "original encoding" field.

Comment: "Interoperable" isn't quite correct, as one does need an explicit conversion. They are round-trippable though, in that every valid UTF-8 stream can be converted to UTF-16 and back again without loss, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

In your application you should use native Unicode support (what the platform uses for storing Unicode). On Windows and OS X this is a sort of `UTF-16`, but on Linux it is `UTF-8`.

When it comes to saving/loading files or communicating with external systems, go for `UTF-8`.

Also, do not confuse code-pages with encodings.

Regarding code-pages, today I think it is not so important to support them anymore. At least it should not be a priority for you. Because for ANSI encodings you do not have BOMs, it will be really hard guess the encoding of files (in fact it is impossible to do it perfectly).

Answer (score 1):

Just decode all the documents to `String`. Strings in .Net are always Unicode (utf-16). Only use encodings when you are reading or writing a file.

Answer (score 0):

When you get ANSI files you should know the codepage before converting to unicode e. g. create a utf-16 string, otherwise the bytes from 128 to 255 could result into the wrong unicode codepoints. You might get into trouble when you want to store unicode string to a ANSI file, because codepoints up to 0x10ffff cannot fit into a single byte.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two reasons to ever use UTF-16 in an interchange format (that is, one that gets sent from A to B):

1. You didn't design the document type, and have to interoperate with something that already uses it.
2. Your content is of such that with some languages UTF-16 is shorter. This is relatively rare as even with those languages, there is often a high number of characters from the BMP in the mix, so UTF-8 ends up being more concise.

Barring that case, there are only two reasons to ever use anything other than UTF-8 in an interchange format:

1. You didn't design the document type, and have to interoperate with something that already uses legacy character sets.
2. You hate people.

Number 2 is particularly pressing if you particularly hate foreigners and people who don't use your own language, but if you just hate people generally, you'll cause enough headaches to enough people that you should find the exercise satisfying.

Now, extending from that, if a given document format designed by someone else allows UTF-8, and you can expect all modern software dealing with it to be able to handle UTF-8, then there are two reasons to not do this:

1. There is some sort of security checks done on the data to make sure it hasn't been changed (note, if you in any way edit or alter the document, this inherently doesn't apply).
2. You hate people. Again with a bonus for xenophobes.

For your internal storing, it's just a matter of whatever is most useful to you. As a rule, .NET tends to default to UTF-16 when in memory (*char* and *string* work with that) and UTF-8 when writing to and reading from strings. If your backing store is a SQL Server, then UTF-16 is your friend (the 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'ntext' variants of 'char', 'varchar', 'text' to avoid issues if the character set was set to anything other than UTF-8), and other databases either have their own way of dealing with modern characters, or can use UTF-8.

In general though, use UTF-8 unless someone forces you to do otherwise (because either they were forced to deal with code from the 1990s or earlier, or because they hate people).